# AngularJs two way data binding implementation error with resources

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, data-binding

I have a page with a couple of controllers and ng-includes.
Before coming to actual problem i should give a little detail about my AngularJS app

It is on top of node and express
It is communicating with passport running on express for authentication
Now i wanted to have the same page for authenticated as well as unauthenticated users with some differences, lets say the first change was the profile option in nav bar -

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right(ng-show="identity.isAuthenticated()")
```

this unordered list has the options to be shown to authenticated users which works fine as soon as i login it is shown which means that the variables **identity** and the method is **isAuthenticate** are working fine
But the problem is with the profile form which is a bootstrap modal box -

```
div.modal.fade(id="profileModal")
    div.modal-dialog
        div.modal-content
            div.modal-header
                button.close(data-dismiss="modal") &times;
                h4 Update Profile
            div.modal-body
                form.form-horizontal(name="profileForm")
                    fieldset
                        .form-group
                            label.col-md-2.control-label(for="email") Email
                            .col-md-10
                                input.form-control(name="email", type="email", placeholder="Email", ng-model="email", required)
                        .form-group
                            label.col-md-2.control-label(for="fname") First Name
                            .col-md-10
                                input.form-control(name="fname", type="text", placeholder="First Name", ng-model="fname", required)
                        .form-group
                            label.col-md-2.control-label(for="lname") Last Name
                            .col-md-10
                                input.form-control(name="lname", type="text", placeholder="Last Name", ng-model="lname", required)
                        .form-group
                            label.col-md-2.control-label(for="password") Password
                            .col-md-10
                                input.form-control(name="password", type="password", placeholder="Password", ng-model="password")
                        .form-group
                            div.modal-footer
                                button.btn.btn-primary(ng-click="update()", ng-disabled="profileForm.$invalid") Submit
                                | &nbsp;

                                a.btn.btn-default(data-dismiss="modal") Cancel
```

Now here i am using a different controller **mvProfileCtrl** which is as follows -

```
angular.module('app').controller('mvProfileCtrl', function($scope, mvAuth, mvIdentity, mvNotifier) {
    $scope.email = mvIdentity.currentUser.username;
    $scope.fname = mvIdentity.currentUser.firstName;
    $scope.lname = mvIdentity.currentUser.lastName;

    $scope.update = function() {
        var newUserData = {
            username: $scope.email,
            firstName: $scope.fname,
            lastName: $scope.lname
        }
        if($scope.password && $scope.password.length > 0) {
            newUserData.password = $scope.password;
        }

        mvAuth.updateCurrentUser(newUserData).then(function() {
            mvNotifier.notify('Your user account has been updated');
        }, function(reason) {
            mvNotifier.error(reason);
        })
    }
})
```

The problem here is as soon as i open the page and the user is not logged in the currentUser is empty object so it doesn't have anything inside it.
So i get this error in console -

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:5000/app/account/mvProfileCtrl.js:2:42)
    at invoke (http://localhost:5000/vendor/angular/angular.js:3899:17)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:5000/vendor/angular/angular.js:3910:23)
    at http://localhost:5000/vendor/angular/angular.js:7164:28
    at http://localhost:5000/vendor/angular/angular.js:6566:34
    at forEach (http://localhost:5000/vendor/angular/angular.js:327:20)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:5000/vendor/angular/angular.js:6553:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:5000/vendor/angular/angular.js:6007:15)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:5000/vendor/angular/angular.js:6014:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:5000/vendor/angular/angular.js:5916:30)
```

But as soon as i refresh the page the currentUser has all the required data and thats why there is no error. So, how do i make sure that when the user is authenticated then only bind the $scope variables to this controller or after that only start the controller.

The project source is a bit big thats why i did not include complete detail here, so if i missed out on any detail please suggest

Edit:: another possible bug after removing the mvIdentity and the currentUser part for debugging when i tried this -

```
angular.module('app').controller('mvProfileCtrl', function($scope, mvAuth, mvNotifier) {



    $scope.update = function() {
        console.log($scope.email);
        var newUserData = {
            username: $scope.email,
            firstName: $scope.fname,
            lastName: $scope.lname
        }
        if($scope.password && $scope.password.length > 0) {
            newUserData.password = $scope.password;
        }

        mvAuth.updateCurrentUser(newUserData).then(function() {
            $('#profileModal').modal('toggle');
            mvNotifier.notify('Your user account has been updated');
        }, function(reason) {
            mvNotifier.error(reason);
        })
    }
});
```

It gave me undefined , which suggests that my $scope is not bound to the profileForm object but if i use the watcher and then use the previous code suggested by then i find that the input elements indeed have the currentUsers firstname and lastname which tells that the $scope is attached there. I am not understanding what is going here, please can anyone explain a bit

i am applying the controller like this -

```
div(ng-include="'/partials/account/authNavBar'",ng-controller="mvProfileCtrl")
```

where authNavBar has this bootstrap modal code and the profileForm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the scope and watchers to your advantage. If you set mvIdentity on your scope with a reference to the service, you can add watchers and only update those properties when currentUser exists.

```
angular.module('app').controller('mvProfileCtrl', function($scope, mvAuth, mvIdentity, mvNotifier) {
    $scope.mvIdentity = mvIdentity;
    $scope.$watch('mvIdentity.currentUser', function(currentUser) {
        if (!currentUser) return;

        $scope.email = currentUser.username;
        $scope.fname = currentUser.firstName;
        $scope.lname = currentUser.lastName;
    });


    $scope.update = function() {
        var newUserData = {
            username: $scope.email,
            firstName: $scope.fname,
            lastName: $scope.lname
        }
        if($scope.password && $scope.password.length > 0) {
            newUserData.password = $scope.password;
        }

        mvAuth.updateCurrentUser(newUserData).then(function() {
            mvNotifier.notify('Your user account has been updated');
        }, function(reason) {
            mvNotifier.error(reason);
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: oh, watchers were just the thing i needed, thanks a lot

Comment: Okay, one doubt does the watchers set the values of these variables as constants or after the find the mvIdentity.currentUser true they continuously set call this function, as when i tried to log the value of username from the update function it gave me the old value from mvIdentity.currentUser instead of the updated value from the form field.